# JSONP callback successful but javascript not updating .html when jQueryMobile included

Tags: ajax, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am building a PhoneGap app using jQuery Mobile.  My JSONP cross domain communication works, but have an issue when jQuery Mobile is included.  ***Without it everything works as expected, included, it stops working.***

I've reduced code to simplest form - Serialize data, encode and call CrossDomain PHP file using JSONP. Execute success function. I thought it might be bad JS but "alert" works and no JS errors.  But the $('#section1').html("SECTION 1 - " + data.message); doesn't update.  ***Note: When I remove jQM it all works!***

Below is the HTML and the PHP code it calls.  It's as though the jQueryMobile AJAX call is interfering with the update of the .html code.  Any ideas?  I'm stumped.

**Ajax4d.htm**

```
<html><head><title>First jQueryMobile Example</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>

  <script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
         $("#foo").submit(function(event) {                
             event.preventDefault();
             var $form = $(this), 
                         $inputs = $form.find("input, select, button, textarea"),
                         serializedData = $form.serialize();
             var postData = serializedData;
             var urlStr = "http://www.fohost.co/testURLd.php?";

             alert (urlStr + encodeURI(postData));                    
             $.ajax({
                  url: urlStr,
                  data: encodeURI(postData),
                  dataType: "jsonp",
                  success: function(data){
                     alert("SUCCESS callback before HTML update: " + data.message);
                     $('#section1').html("SECTION 1 - " + data.message);
                     }
                  });
             });
         }); 
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <section id="register_page" data-role="page" data-theme="b">
        <div data-role="content">
            <form id="foo" method="get" action="">
                <fieldset data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="username">Username:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="Chris" placeholder="Username"/>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset class="ui-grid-a"><input type="submit" value="Send" /></fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div id="section1">SECTION</div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

**testURLd.php**

```
<?php
header("content-type: application/json"); 

$user = $_GET['username'];

$rtnjsonobj->success = "true";
$rtnjsonobj->user = $user;
$rtnjsonobj->message = "Stored User: " . $user;

echo $_GET['callback']. '('. json_encode($rtnjsonobj) . ')';    
?>
```

Comment: have you checked JQM 1.1.0 and jquery 1.7.2 are compatible or not?

Comment: I have and have tried this with both jquery 1.6.4 and 1.7.1 which are both compatible and the same thing happens.  Doesn't work when JQM is included works fine w/o

Comment: I don't yet understand why, but a friend tried the code above and commented out the CSS and it also worked.  So, once I knew that by the process of elimination I was able to discover that the culprit was the following CSS: .fade.out {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 125ms;
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeout;
    -moz-animation-duration: 125ms;
    -moz-animation-name: fadeout;
} not sure what it does, but w/o it everything works.  Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the `submit()` method, but fire an ajax call, you aren't prohibiting the form from submitting.

Add a `return false;` to the end of the `$("#foo").submit` method. This will prohibit the page from reloading onclick.

Answer (score 0):

Use pageinit instead of document ready.. 
check this link..

http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html

try this one..

```
$( document ).delegate("#register_page" ,"pageinit", function() {

     $("#foo").submit(function(event) {                
         event.preventDefault();
         var $form = $(this), 
                     $inputs = $form.find("input, select, button, textarea"),
                     serializedData = $form.serialize();
         var postData = serializedData;
         var urlStr = "http://www.fohost.co/testURLd.php?";

         alert (urlStr + encodeURI(postData));                    
         $.ajax({
              url: urlStr,
              data: encodeURI(postData),
              dataType: "jsonp",
              success: function(data){
                 alert("SUCCESS callback before HTML update: " + data.message);
                 $('#section1').html("SECTION 1 - " + data.message);
                 }
              });
         });
});
```

Comment: Took your suggestion and still no update of #section1.  Found by chance that if I remove .fade.out from jquerymobile css file it will update.  Looking into why this breaks it and here's what I found: The .fadeOut() method animates the opacity of the matched elements. Once the opacity reaches 0, the display style property is set to none, so the element no longer affects the layout of the page.

Comment: EVEN MORE INTERESTING...IF YOU VIEW "GENERATED SOURCE", YOU SEE THE UPDATE IS REALLY THERE, BUT A DUPLICATE DIV IS ALSO THERE WITH THE ORIGINAL PAGE INFO

Comment: Ok looking at both versions (with CSS and w/o) since it's easier than looking into what's going on with the jQM, I see the generated source for both is very similar.  The only difference appears to be when you don't have the jqm css and it works the JQM adds to the first section class with "ui-page-active fade out" and that's not in there when you add in the CSS (which breaks it).  Still unfortunately grabbing at straws.  Somewhere there's a real answer here not just a hack to fix this.